# Como fazer uma Label receber um texto do banco

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms

Olá sei que a pergunta é muito simples, mas estou com uma dificuldade, tenho um radio button e gostaria que o texto dele fosse recebido de um banco de dados SQL Server através de um SELECT.
Estou utilizando o Entity Framework.
Por favor deixem exemplos.

Comment: Como o texto dele está gravado no banco?

Comment: Cara é um quiz que eu estou desenvolvendo, tenho um campo no banco com o nome de "PerguntaUM" e gostaria que o texto desse radiobuton fosse preenchido por esse campo

Comment: O valor da Radio não seria a resposta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade Checked para setar o valor do seu *radioButton*, mas é preciso saber o tipo de dado que esta vindo do seu banco.

A propriedade Checked espera um booleano como valor, então caso você esteja armazenado uma string(varchar) no seu banco, você pode converter a string da seguinte forma.

`radioButton1.Checked =  Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows["PerguntaUM"]);`

contanto que seu valor sejá Yes ou False.

No caso do texto basta você usar a propriedade `Text`.

```
radioButton1.Text = dt.Rows["PerguntaUM"].ToString();
```